# Unable to add user inside Office 365 from SharePoint + Adding the user inside the Office 365 group will not grant permission on the SharePoint site

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, office-365-groups, modern-team-site

I have this weird problem, where we have a modern team site collection >> and using the office 365 admin >> I want to add a user to the underlying Office 365 group >> so I went to SharePoint site  >> clicked on "Site Permission" >> "Invite Users" >> "Add members to group", as follow:-

[image]

but i did not get any option to add the new user, as follow:-

[image]

Also when i went to the Office 365 group and added the user as Members >> wait for around 3 hours now >> the user did not get any permission on the SharePoint site..

so not sure what is going on?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce the issue in my SharePoint Online, go to Microsoft 365 admin center -> Active groups -> Select the group -> Settings -> Set Privacy as Publish. Then wait for few minutes, issues will be solved.

Comment: @Julie_MSFT but i do not want the group to be Public.. as we need the group to stay private.. is this a bug in sharepoint?

Comment: Strictly speaking, this is not a bug.

I test again in my SharePoint Online, even if the group is set to private, you can check the user's permission after waiting for a day.

I suggest you wait longer before doing the test, then compare the result.